# could not find function "multinom" nnet error + stargazer problem

Tags: stargazer, multinomial, nnet

I am trying to run the following multinomial regression specified as follows and get the table as an html through stargazer:

```
    ml1 <- multinom(as.factor(stabgroupsTH) ~  factor(pre_stab_group2) + factor(educ2) + agesup + black + male + mhd + stgyes + highrisk2 +  felony2 + dum_2005,  dd2)
summary(ml1)
stargazer(ml1,type="text")
```

I'm able to run a multinomial logit using `nnet::multinom` but not with only `multinom`. When I try using only `multinom()` I get the error message "could not find function "multinom"". Using `nnet::multinom` runs the model, but when I try to output the regression with stargazer I get the error "% Error: Unrecognized object type." I'm confused by 1) why only `multinom` cannot be found and why stargazer can't recognize the model object. The documentation for stargazer says that multinom is supported.

Thanks,

Simon

Answer (score 3):

Try loading in nnet with `library(nnet)` instead of just calling multinom from the package with `::`. Stargazer should have no problem printing the multinom object.